# Insertando HTML de forma condicional, teniendo en cuenta la presencia o no de un Sibling

Tags: javascript

Estoy implementando la validación de campos de un formulario, y quiero insertar un párrafo, cuando dicha condición se cumpla.
Tengo un markup dentro de una constante, que se inserta en el HTML , con la condición de que el siguiente elemento hermano no sea este markup, con el fin de que sólo se renderice una vez, y no múltiples veces.
Consigo que esto ocurra sin problemas cuando comienzo a llenar los campos desde abajo hacia arriba, pero no ocurre lo mismo cuando lo hago desde arriba hacia abajo, es decir, la condición me da false, por lo tanto se ejecuta la sentencia de renderizado del párrafo, y como resultado tengo el mismo párrafo, muchas veces.

Adjunto HTML:

```
  <div class="upload__column upload__column-2 ">
    <h3 class="upload__heading">Ingredients</h3>
    <!-- <p>Please use format</p> -->
    <label>Ingredient 1</label>
    <input value="0.5,kg,Rice" type="text" required name="ingredient-1"
      placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />

    <label>Ingredient 2</label>
    <input value="1,,Avocado" type="text" name="ingredient-2" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
    <label>Ingredient 3</label>
    <input value=",,salt" type="text" name="ingredient-3" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
    <label>Ingredient 4</label>
    <input type="text" name="ingredient-4" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
    <label>Ingredient 5</label>
    <input type="text" name="ingredient-5" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
    <label>Ingredient 6</label>
    <input type="text" name="ingredient-6" placeholder="Format: 'Quantity,Unit,Description'" />
  </div>
```

- Adjunto Javascript:

```
 _uploadColumnIng = document.querySelector('.upload__column-2').querySelectorAll('input');
 _uploadColumnIng2 = document.querySelector('.upload__column-2');
 _addHandlerTakeInputs() {
        const markup = `<div class='input-err'><p >Please use format</p></div>`;
        const regExp = /[0-9|f| ]\,(gr|ml|kg)\,[A-z]{4,15}$/i;


        this._uploadColumnIng.forEach(el => el.addEventListener
            ('keyup', function () {
                const inputErr = document.querySelector('.input-err');
                if (regExp.test(el.value)) {
                    if (el.nextElementSibling === inputErr) return;
                    el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', markup);
                }
            }))
    }
```

Comment: intenta usar isEqualNode en lugar de === dentro del if: el.nextElementSibling.isEqualNode(inputErr)  asi comparas a los nodos en lugar de a los objetos.

Comment: @davidbug hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ha funcionado perfectamente para los inputs "ingredient-4" e "ingredient-5" , para el "ingredient-6" , recibo el siguiente error: Cannot read property 'isEqualNode' of null at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>

Comment: El error indica que el.nextElementSibling es null por eso que no funciona la propiedad isEqualNode. Se me ocurre logear el.nextElementSibling para confirmar esto, tambien intenta comentando esa linea para ver si se agrega el inputErr

Comment: Solucionado, el problema era que no había un nextElementSibling en el último elemento , agregué un párrafo vacío y funciona sin problemas.  Gracias !